Question PERMEMPT_RT single(userland) single threaded program best practices
Attached is the code how do I make it more clear or have better docs ? I think that I understand how I need to lock the memory and .....

Memory Locking:

Uses mlockall to lock current and future memory allocations, preventing paging.


Thread Attribute

Initialization: Initializes pthread attributes and sets a minimal stack size for the thread.


Scheduling Policy and Priority:

Sets the scheduling policy to SCHED_FIFO and checks that the priority falls within system-supported limits.


Thread Creation and Cleanup:

Creates the thread and waits for it to finish execution. Afterward, it destroys the pthread attributes to release resources.



/*
 * POSIX Real-Time Thread Example with CPU Affinity
 * This code creates a single real-time pthread that performs a dummy math operation in a loop
 * and calculates the time taken for each loop cycle.
 *
 * Compilation:
 * {WHATEVER}-gcc -o rt_example rt_example.c -lrt -lpthread -lm
 */

#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <pthread.h>   // For pthreads and related functions
#include <sched.h>     // For setting scheduling policies and CPU affinity
#include <sys/mman.h>  // For memory locking
#include <math.h>      // For math operations
#include <stdio.h>     // For standard I/O
#include <stdlib.h>    // For standard library functions
#include <limits.h>    // For system limits
#include <time.h>      // For time measurement functions

// GOALS
//  This function is the main task that runs in real-time.
//  It sets the CPU affinity to core 0, performs a dummy math operation in a loop,
//  and measures the elapsed time for each cycle.
//  It prints the elapsed time every 100 cycles.
void *thread_func(void *arg) {
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);          // Initialize CPU set to empty
    CPU_SET(0, &cpuset);        // Set CPU affinity to core 0

    // Attempt to set CPU affinity to CPU 0 for this thread
    if (sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpuset), &cpuset)) {
        perror("sched_setaffinity failed");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Time struct to specify sleep duration
    struct timespec time_requested = {0, 10000000}; // 10 milliseconds

    // Time structs to record start and end times for each loop iteration
    struct timespec start, end;
    float x = 1.5f;  // Dummy variable for math operation

    // Infinite loop to simulate a real-time task
    int count = 0;
    while (1) {
        // Record the start time of this cycle
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

        // Perform a dummy math operation to simulate workload
        x *= sin(x) / atan(x) * tanh(x) * sqrt(x);

        // Sleep for 10 milliseconds to give lower priority threads CPU time
        nanosleep(&time_requested, NULL);

        // Record the end time of this cycle
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

        // Calculate elapsed time in nanoseconds
        long elapsed_ns = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000000L + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);

        // Print elapsed time every 100 cycles to reduce console spam
        if (count++ % 100 == 0) {
            printf("Loop cycle time: %ld ns\n", elapsed_ns);
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}



// GOALS
// Memory Locking:
//      Uses mlockall to lock current and future memory allocations, preventing paging.
// Thread Attribute
//      Initialization: Initializes pthread attributes and sets a minimal stack size for the thread.
// Scheduling Policy and Priority:
//      Sets the scheduling policy to SCHED_FIFO and checks that the priority falls within system-supported limits.
// Thread Creation and Cleanup:
//      Creates the thread and waits for it to finish execution. Afterward, it destroys the pthread attributes to release resources.
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct sched_param param;    // Scheduling parameters structure
    pthread_attr_t attr;         // Thread attributes structure
    pthread_t thread;            // Thread identifier
    int ret;                     // Return value for error checking

    // Lock memory to prevent paging, enhancing real-time performance
    if (mlockall(MCL_CURRENT|MCL_FUTURE) == -1) {
        perror("mlockall failed");
        exit(-2);
    }

    // Initialize thread attributes with default values
    if ((ret = pthread_attr_init(&attr))) {
        perror("pthread_attr_init failed");
        goto out;
    }

    // Set minimum stack size for the thread, can be increased if needed
    if ((ret = pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, PTHREAD_STACK_MIN))) {
        perror("pthread_attr_setstacksize failed");
        goto out;
    }

    // Set scheduling policy to FIFO (First In, First Out) for real-time priority
    if ((ret = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_FIFO))) {
        perror("pthread_attr_setschedpolicy failed");
        goto out;
    }

    // Set the thread's scheduling priority to 79 (within the real-time range)
    param.sched_priority = 79;
    int max_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);
    int min_priority = sched_get_priority_min(SCHED_FIFO);

    // Verify that the priority level is within system-supported limits
    if (param.sched_priority > max_priority || param.sched_priority < min_priority) {
        printf("Priority %d out of range (%d-%d)\n", param.sched_priority, min_priority, max_priority);
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Apply the scheduling parameters to the thread attributes
    if ((ret = pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &param))) {
        perror("pthread_attr_setschedparam failed");
        goto out;
    }

    // Explicitly use the scheduling parameters set in the attributes
    if ((ret = pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED))) {
        perror("pthread_attr_setinheritsched failed");
        goto out;
    }

    // Create the real-time thread using the specified attributes and function
    if ((ret = pthread_create(&thread, &attr, thread_func, NULL))) {
        perror("pthread_create failed, are you root?");
        goto out;
    }

    // Wait for the thread to finish execution (in this case, indefinitely)
    if ((ret = pthread_join(thread, NULL))) {
        perror("pthread_join failed");
    }

out:
    // Clean up the thread attributes after thread creation
    if (pthread_attr_destroy(&attr)) {
        perror("pthread_attr_destroy failed");
        return -1;
    }

    return ret;
}


